# Privacy option not available in 12.10 after update?

Tags: 12.10, privacy

I just updated to ubuntu 12.10 from 12.04. After update I could not see the privacy option available in the settings menu. Did I miss anything during installation?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Strange I have it, do `sudo apt-get install activity-log-manager`

In Software Center it is named

> Activities and Privacy Manager Tool

How did you upgrade to 12.10?
 Here https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/988846

**EDIT:** This will do it `sudo apt-get install activity-log-manager-control-center`